# Filtering a subform table based on parameters in a form

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with two unbounded comboboxes that work fine (one lists several age values and the other lists several region). I have a subform, which is a query that refers to the comboboxes, but I can't get it to update when I change values in the comboboxes.

My query is:

> Select * from mastertable where (age=[form]![masterform]![age] and region=[form]![masterform]![region]

The query works in the sense that if I run it and input the parameters manually it works. It also works in the sense that if I create a button that runs the query on the form, it produces the correct table/query.

My question is how do I get the query to work as a subform? I'd like to be able to select values in the combo box and see the subform update, rather than having to click on a button that runs the query separately from the form.

I also tried creating a table that the parameters on the form can bound to, then relating those variables to the mastertable, but that also didn't work.

How do I get a table/query subform to update as information about the parameters changes in the form? I'm guessing it will require some VBA code on the "after update" event associated with the comboboxes. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just put a little VBA code that requeries the subtable after update.

Code is [subform].requery